# How to access three tables from database

Tags: sql, inner-join

I only know how to access data from 2 different tables but not with 3. How do i do it? Thanks in advance

```
rs.Open("select tblEmp.empID, tblEmp.gn, tblSalary.salary from tblEmp inner join tblSalary on tblEmp.EmpID = tblSalary.EmpID" & "tblPosition.posTitle, tblPosition.posID = tblSalary.posID", con, 3, 3)
    Do Until rs.EOF
        With Me.lv
            .Items.Add(rs.Fields("empID").Value)
            .Items(i).SubItems.Add(rs("gn").Value)
            .Items(i).SubItems.Add(rs("posTitle").Value)
            .Items(i).SubItems.Add(rs("salary").Value)

        End With
    Loop
```

Comment: Please take the time and make the effort to learn how to use this site and don't waste our time spamming tags. None of the tags you used are relevant at all to this question. It's purely a SQL question. You can join as many tables as you like in SQL so you should go and do some SQL research and learn how. It's basically the same as you already have but repeated fir each table. It's not hard to find the information.

Comment: Just add another join. And because this is clearly not visual basic related question, remove vb tags and add proper DBMS tag. And - using CAPS (even in caption only) means shouting :(

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
SELECT t1.FIELDx, t2.FIELDy, t3.FIELDz
  FROM TABLE1 t1
  INNER JOIN TABLE2 t2
    ON t2.KEY1 = t1.KEY1
  INNER JOIN TABLE3 t3
    ON t3.KEY2 = t2.KEY2
```

should do it for you.

Comment: i get a 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Syntax error in FROM clause.' error trying this

Comment: The code in your question which reads `inner join tblSalary on tblEmp.EmpID = tblSalary.EmpID" & "tblPosition.posTitle, tblPosition.posID = tblSalary.posID"` looks wrong to me - perhaps this should be `inner join tblSalary on tblEmp.EmpID = tblSalary.EmpID= tblSalary.posID AND tblPosition.posTitle AND tblPosition.posID = tblSalary.posID"`? That still seems to be mixing tables in an odd way, but I don't know what you're trying to do here so it's tough for me to evaluate this.

Comment: my working code is only from  `select tblEmp.empID, tblEmp.gn, tblSalary.salary from tblEmp inner join tblSalary on tblEmp.EmpID = tblSalary.EmpID`but thats only 2 tables. I need 3